# Rails security concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I am a Java programmer mostly, and it's actually amazing that we don't have to worry about a lot of security concerns that php or even rails developers have to worry about. We have to worry about them, but I think our job is actually a lot easier. You just use Java (already big bonus points there) and use Spring with Spring security... and you're basically done. Java and servlets are actually really good in this respect.

Now that I'm working in Rails, I think the biggest security concerns that I am the most scared of are parameters - both in the ones that are coming from the controllers (since they dynamic hashes, unlike in SpringMVC) and having to include more hidden values in forms.

But that got me thinking - you really have to be careful what you accept when you create new models or even update models. If you just blindly pass in parameters to your models, bad things can happen. In fact, things like the user role and stuff could be changed if you're not too careful.

It's almost like I want to write the setter code by hand to make sure it's not overwriting something that it shouldn't. And even if there's a framework mechanism to handle this... I would still want to test every risky model attribute just to be extra sure that it won't get overwritten on a create and on an update.

As much as Java gets a bad rep about productivity, it feels like it handles this stuff a lot better.

Anyway, my question is - what is the best resource/tips/advice for dealing with common security pitfalls/concerns/gotchas using rails - especially geared towards a Java/Spring developer who got used to working in a more stateful environment.

Even better, what would be a good checklist to go through every once in awhile?

And last, what tests would you recommend to make sure things are solid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use ActiveRecord (I use DataMapper), but as a rule, I *never* do mass-assignment and I always expressly pass only the attributes I want to change.  Rails 3 defaults to escaping all content in your views, unless you expressly output that data raw into into the .erb.

Also, it really bugs me that ActiveRecord doesn't help you out very much if you need to drop down to using SQL for something.  You have to escape input yourself, which can expose you to the risk of human error allowing arbitrary SQL to be executed in your queries.  DataMapper's underlying DataObjects connection supports prepared statements out of the box and in fact, it would actually require more work to avoid using them.

Rails 3 does have CSRF protection turn on by default too.  It also makes session cookies HTTP-only by default, which makes them harder to steal via JavaScript.

I actually think, aside from Rails encouraging the use of mass-assignment, you're pretty well-covered for security.

Comment: ActiveRecord 3.1 (finally) uses prepared statements by default.

Comment: Good info. Would it be possible for you to comment on making new records? For example, in Java, it is really common that when you create a new object, you setup all of it's required associations first... but with Ruby, those associations will be lost when you submit the form if they are not in hidden parameters. So do you set them up when you persist the new object? Also, if you can comment on how you test long parameter lists, that would rock.

Comment: I'm not following you.  Where does the form data come into the associations?  The associations are generally inferred from the URL parameters, if your design is RESTful.  For example, `POST => /posts/:post_id/comments` includes the `:post_id` for which you are making a comment, so first find that `Post`, then create a `Comment` for it.  I'm not clear what you mean though.

Comment: Let's say you have a Role model and a User Model. User associates with a role. You definitely don't want to have a /roles/1/user to create a new user ;) This is something you want to keep behind the scenes, no? So when you do User.new, you can't pass the role yet. In Java, you can - because you can track state on the server. Ruby can't do this unless you pre-persist it. Java runs in memory all the time, unlike Ruby. So the only way I can see to associate a Role with User is when you do the Post action. Correct?

Answer (score 3):

At least for your concern about assigning data to your model objects without proper checking, look into the [`attr_accessible`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-attributes-3D) declaration; it allows only specified attributes to be assigned via the bulk assignment:

```
user = User.new(params[:user])
user.approved = params[:user][:approved]
user.role     = params[:user][:role]
```

You might find the entire 27th chapter of the [Ruby on Rails 3rd edition](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails) book useful. (I haven't updated my [4th Edition](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) book yet, not sure which chapter to recommend from the newer book. :)

Comment: The other [ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html) methods may also be of help.

Comment: I'll definitely look more into these. I am still scared that when you create a new user, set the role, but don't expose the role, my guess is that you have re-set the role again when you persist the user. Right? On updates, it's probably less of a hassle with attr_accessible... but creates seem the most risky.